# Deploying on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, flask

I am looking at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/ but I am not that familiar with Linux web servers.  May I know whether it should be the CGI option or the mod_wsgi (Apache) option that I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I very happy with the [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/)

> nginx [engine x] is an HTTP and reverse proxy server, a mail proxy server, and a generic TCP proxy server, originally written by Igor Sysoev. For a long time, it has been running on many heavily loaded Russian sites including Yandex, Mail.Ru, VK, and Rambler. According to Netcraft, nginx served or proxied 24.33% busiest sites in January 2016. Here are some of the success stories: Netflix, Wordpress.com, FastMail.FM.

and [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/)

> Gunicorn 'Green Unicorn' is a Python WSGI HTTP Server for UNIX. It's a pre-fork worker model ported from Ruby's Unicorn project. The Gunicorn server is broadly compatible with various web frameworks, simply implemented, light on server resources, and fairly speedy.

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) is a good article about deployment on the linux platform with the flask.